# Is $P(C \cup D) = P( D \cup C)$?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

Intuitively, I can understand that if an event C occurs with some probability P(C) AND event D occurs with some probability P(D), then drawing a venn diagram of them it wouldn't matter whether the C or D came first.
However, I can't seem to find anything to back this up and thus don't feel comfortable using this 'identity'.  Can anyone confirm this for me?

Comment: Yes. But more fundamentally $C\cup D = D \cup C$ as sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is always true because $C\cup D = D\cup C$ as sets.